# woocommerce related products 2 column issues for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, multiple-columns

Morning all,

I can't seem to get my Woocommerce related products to show in a 2 column, side by side format. When viewed on **mobile device**

You will see on this page that the related products are one after another, id like 2 side by side before a new row starts. https://ruggedasylum.com/product/solo-smoke-free-fire-pit/

Can someone assist me with how this is achieved, please?

I have tried this so far but it only makes smaller and continues to place 1 product on each line. It also moved the 'Related Products' title across to the left instead of centered.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.woocommerce .related.products {
width: 50% !important;
}}
```

I have gone onto W3 Schools and the CSS code they suggest for side by side in a responsive view doesn't seem to make a difference, less so than the code above.

please note I am happy with the way it is currently looking on the desktop version of the page.

I look forward to your input, a very grateful Ryan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px){

   .related.products ul.products li.product {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 45%;

  }
}
```

that should do the trick but you might want to adjust % 
for more info on flexbox, u can visit this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hey Ashraf, Thanks for the code. It doesn't appear to make any changes. Does it relate to all products throughout my site or the specific section for related products on each single product page? Maybe i need to change .products to .related.products. Oh and thanks for the link ill check that out.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice I made a mistake with class, I've updated my code, u can be more specific or if you want this to apply to all product column the remove the related class and leave it as ```ul.products li.prosduct```

Comment: This is greatly appreciated! The only problem now is this applies to the first row only. see https://ruggedasylum.com/product/solo-smoke-free-fire-pit/ on mobile. thanks.

Comment: It appears that has happened because there is very little in terms of related products for that particular page and is giving back an odd number of products! 3 in this case. Other products offering 2,4,6,8 etc products are working. Thanks!

Comment: I made an adjustment to code, should help with odd number, let me know that works. you can also adjust width % to makes sure there is enough space for column margin or padding

Comment: Absolutely perfect Ashraf, thank you for your help. Stay safe. The final edit has completed what I was hoping for. Greatly appreciated.